# Vertically center a line in wpf

Tags: wpf, line

The following code does not seem to center the line vertically; e.g. the stroke thickness do not seem to be taken into account in arranging the line:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32" Height="32">
    <Line Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" X2="32"
       Stroke="Black"
       StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" />
</Grid>
```

What's missing?

Comment: Are you sure your Binding is working? You shall check output for data binding errors. Try to set StrokeThickness manually to some number to make sure StrokeThickness itself if OK.

Comment: How could i see the line if the binding was not working?

Comment: I assume you use some kind of model (which is referenced by DataContent of parent ui elements), If this fails, and DataContext stays null, Binding will not work. How to check if it is null: try StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness, FallbackValue=100}". In this case, you will have thickness 100 if DataContext is null.

Comment: Otherwise, if DataContext references wrong object, you will find in Output window something like "System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'StrokeThickness' property not found on 'object' ''MyModel' (HashCode=17961330)'. BindingExpression:Path=StrokeThickness; DataItem='MyModel' (HashCode=17961330); target element is 'Line' (Name=''); target property is 'StrokeThickness' (type 'Double')"

Comment: @AlexeyPavlov I was being sarastic :) the binding works the problem was a DesiredSize miscalculation in WPF solved with a Canvas as JamesDurda explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it may have something to do with `StrokeThickness` not changing the `DesiredSize` of the `Line` element but you can work around it:

The `Grid` can be replaced with a `Canvas`:

```
<Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32" Height="32">
    <Line Stretch="None" X2="32" Y1="16" Y2="16"
          Stroke="Black"
          StrokeThickness="15" />
</Canvas>
```

Or, if you need the outer `Grid`, wrap the `Line` in a `Canvas`:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32" Height="32" >
    <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Line Stretch="None" X2="32" 
               Stroke="Black"
               StrokeThickness="15" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Perfect! How did you know was a grid problem and the canvas worked around it?

Comment: I've had experience with a thick border being clipped before so I knew that `StrokeThickness` doesn't change the `DesiredSize` and `Grid` does a lot of arranging for you so it is likely to be confused by the thick `Line`. Using [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) quickly confirmed what was happening.